# mistaken override from github how to cancel?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, github

I did big mistake.

could I back up? (the recent version is not on github)

I only have recent application (code/program) inside my emulator

but code is completely messed up

I really want a help

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio, it uses its own Version Control.
Click on VCS > Local History > Show History from where you can travel back to where the code was working.

Comment: I tried just now but the Show History button is not clickable